# ValueError: dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of bytes/strings.Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead

Tags: predictive-modeling, deployment

I am new to machine learning model deployment. In a sequence, local system rises an error while running "app.py" file, that is:

```
"ValueError: dtype='numeric' is not compatible with arrays of 
bytes/strings.Convert your data to numeric values explicitly instead."
```

[image: Selected features and even target is numeric but still error is triggerederror while running "app.py"]

Comment: the error message says that your sequence contains numerical values, which is true according to your picture. But you are trying to use it in a function call (or whatever) that needs byte or strings. We can not say more since you don't provide the code that returns this error. Please provide it for more accurate answer.